# Celery Beat on Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-ecs, celerybeat

I am using Amazon Web Services ECS (Elastic Container Service).
My task definition contains Application + Redis + Celery and these containers are defined in task definition. Automatic scaling is set, so at the moment there are three instances with same mirrored infrastructure. However, there is a demand for a Celery Beat instance for scheduled tasks, so Celery Beat would be a great tool, since Celery is already in my infrastructure.

But here is the problem: if I add Celery Beat container together with other containers (add it to task definition), it will be mirrored and multiple instances will execute same scheduled tasks at the same moment. What would be a solution to this infrastructure problem? Should I create a seperate service?

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

We use [`single-beat`](https://github.com/ybrs/single-beat) to solve this problem and it works like a charm:

> Single-beat is a nice little application that ensures only one
>   instance of your process runs across your servers.
>
> Such as celerybeat (or some kind of daily mail sender, orphan file
>   cleaner etc...) needs to be running only on one server, but if that
>   server gets down, well, you go and start it at another server etc.

You should still set the number of desired tasks for the service to 1.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ECS Task Placement strategy to place your Celery Beat task and choose "One Task Per Host". Make sure to choose Desire state to "1". In this way, your celery beat task will run only in 1 container in your cluster.

> Ref:
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_run_task.html

The desired task is the number of tasks you want to run in the cluster. You may set the "Number of tasks" while configuring the service or in the run task section. You may refer the below links for references.

Configuring service:

> Ref:
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-service.html

Run Task:

> Ref:
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_run_task.html

Let me know if you find any issue with it.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response, I think it may really lead me to the solution. But I can't find where to set the desire state.

Comment: You can define the "Number of task" while configuring service or while running the task. I have updated the answer with reference link.

Comment: Thank you. Everything seems clear now. However, there is one more question from cluster architecture. Main task definition already has Redis container and it could be reused in the task definition that is used for CeleryBeat task. But after making a quick research, I've found out that linking containers between seperate task definitions is not possible. Does it mean I should create another Redis container for Beat task? It won't make much sense I guess.

Comment: Yup, this is something where you have to use service discovery. You may use any tool available in the market say weave, consul or with ALB where each target group assigned to one service and you may use that ALB hostname in private route53 hosted zone.

Comment: There are many informative articles available on stackoverflow or google regarding service discovery on ecs. You can follow that.

Comment: @smuctic Can you accept this as a solution? If it works for you.